How to trigger a .glb animation (animation mixer) at the same time as an A-frame animation property animation?
How to trigger a .glb animation (animation mixer) at the same time as an A-frame animation property animation?

I have three animations I want to play:

Walking animation that is baked into the .glb model. I play it using A-frame's animation mixer.
Animate position and scale from an event called walk-in. They're both properties of the a-entity.

Is there a way where I can play both simultaneously? Or will I need to bake in an animation that does all three at once?

Here is the simplified entity code:
<a-entity
      gltf-model="#peacock-glb"
      position="5 0.17 -5"
      scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"
      id="peacock-entity"
      animation__position="property: position; to: 0.2 0.6 4.5; delay:1500; dur: 4500; startEvents: walk-in"
      animation__scale="property: scale; to: 0.05 0.05 0.05; delay:1500; dur: 4500; startEvents: walk-in">
</a-entity>

Here is the javascript code where I try to trigger the animation property and the animation mixer animation called Walking. It seems to play Walking first, then plays the two animation properties for the walk-in event.
Edit: After Piotr's comment, I tried removing the delay, but that seems to have the animation property override the Walking animation-mixer animation entirely.
this.el.emit('walk-in', null, false)
this.el.setAttribute('animation-mixer', 'clip:Walking')


did you take into account the 1500 delay in your animations?

@PiotrAdamMilewski ah, thank you for pointing that out! But unfortunately that doesn't seem to fix the issue. After changing it to no delay, it doesn't play the Walking animation at all. It seems like the animation-mixer is being overridden by the animation property...

Any chance you could upload the code on glitch.com or somewhere?
